# https url in Spring ClassPathXmlApplicationContext

Tags: java, spring, https

I used a Spring *SingletonBeanFactoryLocator* and the xml file passed to *.getInstance()* method contains this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE beans PUBLIC "-//SPRING//DTD BEAN//EN" "http://www.springframework.org/dtd/spring-beans.dtd">
<beans default-lazy-init="true"> 
<bean id="it.rules.bean.commands" 
     class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext" >
 <constructor-arg>
   <list>
    <value>https://aPathToFolder/commands.xml</value>
   </list>
  </constructor-arg>
 </bean>
</beans>
```

I receive a 401 error caused, I think, because of the https URL.

Is there any way to use https URLs in a *ClassPathXmlApplicationContext* directly in Spring? Or is there a best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say: `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext` is designed class path related resources, not for http/https!

> Standalone XML application context,
>   taking the context definition files
>   from the class path, interpreting
>   plain paths as class path resource
>   names that include the package path
>   (e.g. "mypackage/myresource.txt").
>   Useful for test harnesses as well as
>   for application contexts embedded
>   within JARs.

From the [Java Doc of `ClassPathXmlApplicationContext`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/support/ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.html).

---

What you can try, is to exchange the ResourceLoader by one that is able to load the configuration file via HTTP(s).

@See `public int loadBeanDefinitions(String location, Set<Resource> actualResources)` of class `org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader`

Comment: I've changed the approach as you suggest. Thanks :)